# Problema con el adapter en el HomeFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy creando un RecycledView en el HomeFragment, en el contexto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Al inicializar el adapter al MainAdapter ya creado me da error el this, tabmién he probado con un requireContext() pero sigue sin funcionar.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var adapter: MainAdapter
private val ViewModels : MainViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    adapter = MainAdapter(this)

    rvHobbies.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    rvHobbies.adapter = adapter
    observeData()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}

fun observeData(){
    ViewModels.fetchHobbieData().observe(this, Observer {
        adapter.setListData(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El argumento `this` debe ser una referencia a un contexto, y un `Fragment` no es un contexto. En una `Activity` funciona usar `this` porque una `Activity` es un contexto.

Por lo tanto, si te encuentras en un `Fragment`, usa como contexto la `Activity` que cargará el `Fragment` mediante `activity` de esta forma:

```
 adapter = MainAdapter(activity)
```